# Given $P(B\mid A)=1-\varepsilon$ for some $0<\varepsilon<1$ and $P(C\mid B)=1$, prove that $P(C\mid A)≥1-\varepsilon$

Tags: probability-theory

We need to show that, given $P(B\mid A)=1-\varepsilon$ for some $0<\varepsilon<1$ and $P(C\mid B)=1$, that $P(C\mid A)≥1-\varepsilon$. Since we know that $P(C\mid B)=1$, it follows that $P(B \cap C)=P(B)$. This however, doesn't really help much. I tried a lot of things, but I couldn't prove this question, although it seems pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question to include what things you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $P(B\text{ }|\text{ }A)=1-\epsilon$ and $P(C\text{ }|\text{ }B)=1$ then $P(C\text{ }|\text{ }A)\geq 1-\epsilon$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648005/if-pb-text-text-a-1-epsilon-and-pc-text-text-b-1-then-pc)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as you mentioned, we have : $P(B)=P(B\cap C)$.
Now consider the following
$$\begin{align}
P(B\cap A)&=P(B)-P(B\cap A^c)\\
&=P(B\cap C)-P(B\cap A^c)\\
&\leq P(B\cap C)-P(C\cap B\cap A^c)=P(B\cap C \cap A)\\
&\leq P(C\cap A).
\end{align}$$
Now it is easy to see that : 
$$
P(B\mid A)=1-\epsilon\leq P(C\mid A).
$$