# If $P(B\text{ }|\text{ }A)=1-\epsilon$ and $P(C\text{ }|\text{ }B)=1$ then $P(C\text{ }|\text{ }A)\geq 1-\epsilon$

Tags: probability, bayesian

If $$1=P(C\text{ }|\text{ }B)=\frac{P(C\cap B)}{P(B)}$$ then we know that $P(C\cap B)=P(B)$. If $P(B\text{ }|\text{ }A)=1-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon\geq 0$ then $$P(A)=\frac{P(B\cap A)}{1-\epsilon}$$Using this I found that $$P(C\text{ }|\text{ }B)=(1-\epsilon)\frac{P(C\cap A)}{P(B\cap A)}$$
Now I have to show that $$\frac{P(C\cap A)}{P(B\cap A)}\geq 1$$ I don't know how to use the first assumption to show this. I need hints. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can look at here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647948/given-pba-1-varepsilon-for-some-0-varepsilon1-and-pcb-1-prove-th/648008#648008

Comment: $P(C\mid A)=\frac{P(C\cap A)}{P(A)}=\frac{P((C\cap A)\cap B)+P((C\cap A)\setminus B)}{P(A)}$.

Comment: @Arash thanks for the link!